# Rendering Multiple Files with pystache

Tags: python, pyramid

How do you use partial layouts in pystache?  I haven't been able to find any documentation for doing this.  I'm looking for something along the lines of

layout.html

```
<html>
   <body>
     {{<body}}
  </body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
<section>
    {{name}}
</section>
```

Edit:

I've done this using node.js and am familiar with the templating syntax, but I'm not sure how to tell pystache to load both files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pystache is just a Python implementation of Mustache, so the Mustache documentation should apply to Pystache as well. Check out the [Partials section](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html#Partials) of the man page.

`layout.mustache`

```
<html>
   <body>
     {{> body}}
  </body>
</html>
```

`body.mustache`

```
<section>
    {{name}}
</section>
```

---

Here's an example of rendering the above templates in Pystache (from the same directory as the `.mustache` files):

```
>>> import pystache
>>> renderer = pystache.Renderer()
>>> renderer.render_path('layout.mustache', {'name': 'test'})
u'<html>\r\n   <body>\r\n     <section>\r\n         test\r\n     ...'
```

For more info, check out the [Pystache source](https://github.com/defunkt/pystache/blob/master/pystache/renderer.py).

Comment: I'm not having trouble creating the mustache files, but using the pystache API to accomplish this

Comment: @wegrata: Updated answer with an example.

Comment: How do you specify body.mustache? or does it assume body.mustache based on the name off of {{<body}}?

Comment: @wegrata: Yes, if you don't specify partials directly, it'll try to find them from the name (which is `{{> body}}`, not `{{< body}}`).